# Can you verify my solutions to these probabilities, given a coin is flipped 10 times?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I'm fresh into probability and I think it's important to ask a lot of questions since it seems probability really challenges your intuition. I'm working on the following problem, and have found a solution for each, but I'd like to verify my understanding is correct.

I'm not entirely sure on part c (this IS the intersection, right? Is it simply just multiplying the two probabilities together, or is there something I'm missing? The formula below part c makes me nervous I'm missing something).

> A coin is flipped 10 times.
>   a) What is the probability that there are exactly five heads and five tails?
>   b) What is the probability that the first three flips are heads?
>   c) What is the probability that there are exactly five heads and five tails AND the first three flips are heads?
>   d) What is the probability that there are exactly five heads and five tails OR the first three flips are heads?

Let $(S, P)$ be a sample space such that $$S = \{(a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_{10}) : a_1 \in \{H, T\}\}$$ and $P(S) = \frac{1}{2^{10}}$ for all $s \in S$.

**a)** By definition, $|S| = 1024$. Let $E$ be the event that we get 5 heads (so the other five flips are tails). Then $|E| = $$10 \choose 5$, because we are choosing 5 of the 10 flips to be heads. Since all outcomes are equally likely, $P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|} = \frac{252}{1024}$.

**b)** For each of the first three flps, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance that each one will be heads. By the multiplication principle, the probability that the first three flips are heads is $\frac{1}{2^3} = \frac{1}{8}$.

**c)** From part $a$, we know that the probability of exactly five heads and five tails is $\frac{252}{1024}$. From part $b$, we know the probability that the first three flips are heads is $\frac{1}{8}$. So the probability of both is $A \cap B = P(A) * P(B) = \frac{63}{2048}$ (defining $A$ as the event of exactly five heads and tails, and $B$ as the event of the first three flips being heads).

**d)** We have the formula $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$. Using our $A$ and $B$ events from part $c$, $P(A) = \frac{252}{1024}$, $P(B) = \frac{1}{8}$, and $P(A \cap B) = \frac{63}{2048}$. So we have that $$P(A \cup B) = \frac{252}{1024} + \frac{1}{8} - \frac{63}{2048} = \frac{697}{2048}$$.

Comment: c) is not right, the events are not independent.

Comment: Part c is wrong, hence part d. It's good to make mistakes, and I'll point this one out. So part c says, first three coins are heads AND there are exactly five heads and tails. When you hear AND, you **do not multiply** by default. The events are dependent, because one depends on the other : if the first three tosses are heads, it doesn't allow the rest to the tosses to behave normally, because only 2 of the remaining 7 can be heads. Use this logic to refine c, and hence d, whose formula is correct.

Comment: Should I use the formula $P(B|A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$?

Comment: @dewick49 That would work.

Comment: Is there a simple way to find $P(A \cap B)$ here? I'm having trouble finding it without writing the whole set out. Or is that essentially what Andre is saying in his answer?

Answer (score 2):

c) The probability the first $3$ are heads is, as you wrote, $\frac{1}{8}$.

The (conditional) probability that we end up with $5$ of each, **given** that the first $3$ were heads, is the probability of $2$ heads in the next $7$ throws. This is $\frac{\binom{7}{2}}{2^{7}}$.

Thus our required probability is $\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{\binom{7}{2}}{2^{7}}$.

*Remark*: a) and b) were right. For d), your method is fine, with suitable correction for $\Pr(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Is there a way to express this answer with the formula in the above comments, out of curiosity?

Comment: Yes, let $B$ be the event first three are heads, and let $A$ be the event $5$ of each. We want $\Pr(A\cap B)$. Now use the fact that $\Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$, or equivalently $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)$. In my answer, I computed $\Pr(A\mid B)$ as $\binom{7}{2}/2^7$, then multiplied by $1/8$. So in essence I used the conditional probability formula, without thinking of what I was doing as using a formula.

Comment: Ah, I see! Fantastic. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.